# Web scraping using javascript

Tags: javascript, web, web-scraping

I want to make a site (with HTML, CSS and Javascript) which will scrape data from other sites. I want to use javascript in order to accomplish that. Which is the best way to do it? I would like to avoid using Node.js or some other framework.

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting cors error just use [cors anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/).

For dom parsing use [DomParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Example:

```
fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/${url}`)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(html => {
  const parser = new DOMParser()
  const dom = parser.parseFromString(htmlContent, 'text/html')
  // now you can select elements like for normal node
  dom.querySelector('div')
})
```

Do you have any other problems?

Comment: Konrad thanks for the answer. So are you against of Node.js usage for this purpose?

Comment: I'm not against. But hosting a node.js server isn't as simple as hosting a webpage.